Rusted steel rivet nut on aluminum frame causing frame to corrode
I have an aluminum-framed hybrid which has rivet nuts set in it for mounting racks and fenders. I am pretty sure these are steel rivet nuts because they seem to be rusting and causing corrosion on the aluminum frame. Including picture of one example here:

My questions are:

Will this corrosion hurt the structural integrity of the frame.
If not, can the exposed aluminum cause problems (e.g. become more seriously corroded because of road salt during winter riding.)
If there are potential problems, what can I do to fix the corrosion and keep it from corroding in the future?

I don't think I have the equipment to remove the rivet nuts or reinstall new ones, so I would prefer suggestions that avoid that.

Salt corrosion is a serious concern for Al., often overlooked.

Has there ever been something mounted to the frame on this spot? It does not look like pure corrosion to me. I would expect to see more separation or corrosion in between the rivet and the metal of the frame rather than surrounding the rivet. The rivet should be getting lose.

@DavidD I have no idea, it was like this when I got it. Point taken though. The rivet on the inside of the triangle had a bolt seized that I had to drill out, not sure if that gives any extra info.

Scrape off the damaged paint and white aluminium oxide powder. Wire brush to clean metal and paint with vehicle touch up paint. Don't allow the corrosion to get worse.
You could drill out the rivnut and replace it: A rivnut setting kit is not expensive. Tidying up the paint will resolve the problem temporarily but if the alu deteriorates too much around the rivnut, it may loosen and bolt removal then becomes tricky.

This is good advise.   Replacing the rivnut is feasible though there's almost always a piece left inside the frame that may be impossible to remove. plus the hole will get slightly enlarged.   I'd wire-brush the white alu oxide off, and apply some kind of rust converter to the rivnut.  Then I'd chase the threads with a M5 (?) tap.  Finally I'd install a well-greased bolt even if there's nothing secured here.  A plastic one would be fine as a stopper.

@Criggie would a rust converter penetrate between the rivnut and the frame?

@LucasMyers Probably not - it would depend on how "runny" the converter fluid is.  A gel won't get in there at all, something more like water could wick in.   Gravity may help too.
